# Angular: Having a routerlink on a button

Tags: angular

I am trying to have a routerlink but I am having some problems. Clicking the button does not do anything. I can navigate to the page via url directly and the route fine

I want to go to /addEditControl/{{controlId}}

In SelfServiceDetails.component.ts is the controlId which is the input

```
@Component({
selector: 'self-service-details',
templateUrl: '../templates/self-service-details.component.html',
providers: [SelfServiceDetailsService,ControlSpecificDataService]
})

export class SelfServiceDetailsComponent {
@Input() controlId: string; 

}}
```

In my HMTL component I am setting the router on the button like this

```
<button  routerLink="/addEditControl/{{controlId}}">Onboard Control</button>
```

My appRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ControlsListComponent } from './components/controls-list.component';
import { ControlDetailsComponent } from './components/controlDetails.component';
import { ControlHistoryListComponent } from './components/control-history-list.component';
import { MyControlsComponent } from './components/myControls.component';
import { SnowDataComponent } from './components/snowData.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/pageNotFound.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from 'app/components/landingPage.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './components/home-page.component';
import { ControlDetailGuard } from './services/control-detail-guard.service';
import { AddEditControlComponent } from './SelfServiceForm/add-edit-control.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'addEditControl/:id', component: AddEditControlComponent},  
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Edit: The controlId is being populated correctly, i have tested this with `<p>{{controlId}}</p>`

Comment: enclose your button into an "anchor" tag for example 
<a routerLink= ""> <button  routerLink="['/addEditControl/', controlId]">Onboard Control</button></a>

Comment: can you inspect and see if the value `{{controlId}}` is interpolated correctly ?

Comment: @SajjadAli that's not necessary

Comment: It should be `[routerLink]="['/addEditControl', controlId]"`. If controlId is correct, then this should work. But why do you use a button and not a link? Button is not the semantically correct element to use. Use links to navigate. Not buttons.

Comment: Do like this <button  routerLink="{{'/addEditControl/'+controlId}}">Onboard Control</button>

Comment: most probably your `controlId` is empty check by inspecting the link

Comment: also just asking have you placed the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` correctly

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic link you suppose to do following thing

> dynamic property binding

```
<button  [routerLink]="['/addEditControl', controlId ]">Onboard Control</button>
```

Comment: that's not the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You should use RouterLink on a button like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/admin/home', param to pass]"
```

You need to include [] around routerLink.

Answer (score -1):

This is not how it is supposed to be done. If you want to navigate with a button, then call the function and pass the string where u want to navigate => addEditControl('controlID')

and in your .ts file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

addEditControl(link:string) {
this.router.navigate([link]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution1 :**
 Put your button inside an a href :

```
<a routerLink="/addEditControl/{{controlId}}"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Onboard Control</button></a>
```

**Solution2:** onClick button navigate to your page!

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) { }
    onClick= function () {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/addEditControl/'+this.controlId);
    };
```

Comment: Please NEVER put a button inside a link. It's not valid html